# How to use jax vmap for nested loops?

Tags: python, performance, vectorization, jit, jax

I want to use vmap to vectorise this code for performance.

```
def matrix(dataA, dataB):
    return jnp.array([[func(a, b) for b in dataB] for a in dataA])
matrix(data, data)
```

I tried this:

```
def f(x, y):
    return func(x, y)
mapped = jax.vmap(f)
mapped(data, data)
```

But this only gives the diagonal entries.

Basically I have a vector `data = [1,2,3,4,5]` (example), I want to get a matrix such that each entry `(i, j)` of the matrix is `f(data[i], data[j])`. Thus, the resulting matrix shape will be `(len(data), len(data))`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`jax.vmap` maps across one set of axes at a time. If you want to map across two independent sets of axes, you can do so by nesting two `vmap` transformations:

```python
mapped = jax.vmap(jax.vmap(f, in_axes=(None, 0)), in_axes=(0, None))
result = mapped(data, data)
```